# Showing message of response received in case of OnFailure condition of Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, response, okhttp

I am trying to print the response message when isSuccess is false from data coming from an api call. However, in response i am getting isSuccess= false but when I try to print the message it says that data is null. Please help me with this issue.

This is the class where i am calling my api and observing the partsDetailData. It enters in the else loop instead of entering false loop although i am getting isSuccess as false. Postman result says 200.

**Expectation: Showing "Part - 5272018 is superseded to new Part number - 6164702" as a toast which is received in response on calling partsDetailApi in case of isSuccess=false.**

When debugged, the data is null here.

ProductPriceAvailablity.kt

```
val partsDetailsData = MutableLiveData<Resource<BaseResponse<PartsDetailsResponse>>>()    

productDetailEtaVM.partsDetailsData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it.let {
                dismissProgressBar()
                when(it.data?.isSuccess){
                    true ->{
                        //some code
                    }
                    false ->{
                    //**I want to enter in this condition**
                        putToast(it.data.message)

                    }
                    else ->{
                    //**My code enters in this condition** 
                        putToast("Sorry! You are not authorized to Order this Part.")

                    }
                }
            }
       })
```

ProductDetailEtaViewModel.kt

```
fun partsDetailsApi(){
        mShowProgressBar.value = true
        LoginControllerRepository.getInstance().partsDetailsApi(partsDetailsData,Constants.materialNo,Constants.sourceSupply,
                currentDateApi(),Constants.quantity!!,sharedPreference?.getString(Constants.customerCode)!!,sharedPreference?.getString(Constants.customerCode)!!,sharedPreference?.getString(Constants.customerCode)!!,"00","10")
    }
```

Repositoryclass.kt

```
fun partsDetailsApi(responseData: MutableLiveData<Resource<BaseResponse<PartsDetailsResponse>>>, materialNo: String, sourceSupply: String,
                        pricingValidon : String, quantify : String, shipTo : String, soldTo : String, billTo : String, division : String, distChannel : String){
        apiService.loginUser()?.partsDetailsApi(materialNo = materialNo,sourceSupply = sourceSupply,pricingValidon = pricingValidon,
                quantity = quantify,shipTo = shipTo,soldTo = soldTo,billTo = billTo,division = division,distChannel = distChannel)
                ?.enqueue(getCallback(responseData))
    }
```

InterfaceClass.kt

```
@GET("Parts/PartsDetails?")
    fun partsDetailsApi(
            @Query("MaterialNo") materialNo : String,
            @Query("Sourcesupply") sourceSupply : String,
            @Query("PricingValidon") pricingValidon : String,
            @Query("Quantity") quantity : String,
            @Query("ShipTo") shipTo : String,
            @Query("SoldTo") soldTo : String,
            @Query("BillTo") billTo : String,
            @Query("Division") division : String,
            @Query("DistChannel") distChannel : String
    ) : Call<BaseResponse<PartsDetailsResponse>>
```

Response

```
{"isSuccess":false,"message":"Part - 5272018 is superseded to new Part number - 6164702","response":"Error"}
```

Resource.kt

```
data class Resource<out T>(val status: Status, val data: T?, val message: String?) {
    companion object {
        fun <T> success(data: T): Resource<T> = Resource(status = Status.SUCCESS, data = data, message = null)

        fun <T> error(message: String,data: T?): Resource<T> =
            Resource(status = Status.ERROR, data = data, message = message)

        fun <T> loading(data: T?): Resource<T> = Resource(status = Status.LOADING, data = data, message = null)
    }
}
```

BaseRepository.kt

When done debugging, my compiler enter in OnFailure condition.

```
package com.app.gmmcoassist.data.repository

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.app.gmmcoassist.utils.Resource
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import java.io.IOException

open class BaseRepository {
    private val noNetworkMsg = "No internet connection or network failure"

    fun <T> getCallback(responseData: MutableLiveData<Resource<BaseResponse<T>>>): Callback<BaseResponse<T>> {
        return object : Callback<BaseResponse<T>> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<BaseResponse<T>>, t: Throwable) {
                val msg = if (t is IOException) noNetworkMsg else t.message!!
                responseData.value = Resource.error(msg, null)
                System.out.println("getCallBackaaa"+"response.code()")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<BaseResponse<T>>, response: Response<BaseResponse<T>>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                    responseData.value = Resource.success(response.body()!!)
                    System.out.println("getCallBack::::"+response.code())
                } else if (response.errorBody() != null) {
                    //val errorResponse = getErrorResponse<T>(response.errorBody()!!)
                    System.out.println("getCallBack"+response.code())
                     responseData.value = Resource.error(response.code().toString(), null)
                    if (response.code() == 204){
                        responseData.value = Resource.error(response.code().toString(), null)
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }

    fun <T> getCallbackList(responseData: MutableLiveData<Resource<BaseResponse<List<T>>>>): Callback<BaseResponse<List<T>>> {
        return object : Callback<BaseResponse<List<T>>> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<BaseResponse<List<T>>>, t: Throwable) {
                val msg = if (t is IOException) noNetworkMsg else t.message!!
                responseData.value = Resource.error(msg, null)
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, so I got the issue sorted. The response that I was receiving was a String due to which it was giving me IllegalStateException, json was not parsed successfully.

```
{"isSuccess":false,"message":"Part - 5272018 is superseded to new Part number - 6164702","response":"Error"}
```